POST requests in Project IDX (Express and Nodejs)
I'm currently building a Gemini web application using the online IDE Google IDX. However, when trying to send POST requests from the frontend(JS) to the backend(ExpressJS server), I keep getting this error:
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

I have tried setting permissions within the server file such as:
app.use(cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        callback(null, true);  
    },
    credentials: true
}));


Because there is no way that I know of to reference Project IDX frontend files like backend files.
The same error still occurs using this method and even when using '*' to accept all origins.
If anybody has any knowledge about how I could bypass this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

did you put credentials: true in your frontend?

This issue arises when we try to send post requests from the frontend to the backend and both the domains mismatch.
in your backend "access-control-allow-credentials" we need to set true, which allows the credentials and makes sure you are not setting "access-control-allow-origin"  as '*' as sending '*' while sending credentials will fail the request.
you can fix this by setting these to you frontend backend configuration.
Backend example :
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // your frontend origin
    credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies, headers)
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'], // Allow the necessary methods
}));

Frontend example :
fetch('http://localhost:5000/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include', // Ensure cookies/credentials are sent
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' }) // Replace with your request data
})

